# trouble with accordion I am making

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an accordion for school and I feel like it should work. I know I have everything right up until the if else statement. Any suggestions appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //
    // Set up a click event handler for clicked <li>
    //
    $('#accordion li').click(function() {

        // find first ul that is a child of this (the clicked <li>)
        var $nextUL = $(this).children('ul:first-child');

        // Select all siblings of the clicked <li> and then 
        // select any direct children <ul>'s 
        // that are visible - this is so we can close any visible
        // <ul> before opening the <ul> for the clicked <li>
        var $visibleSiblings = $(this).siblings().children('ul:visible');

        // If any other <ul>s are visible, slide the visible <ul>
        // up and then, after the slide up is complete, slide down 
        // the clicked <li>'s <ul> into view
        if ($visibleSiblings.length > 0) {
             $visibleSiblings.slideUp('normal', function() {
             $nextUL.fadeIn('normal');
             });

        } else {
            // either no <ul>s were open (open the clicked item)
            // or the user clicked on the currently open one so close it
            $nextUL.slideToggle('normal');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any HTML to go with it so we can test?

Comment: Nothing seems irregular in logic.Would have expected `fadeIn()` to be `slideDown()` though for an accordion. What is/isn't it doing? A demo in jsfiddle.net would help.

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle before but here is a shot. http://jsfiddle.net/m6fo2z4y/1/

Comment: i basically want a item to slideDown open and when another item is clicked that one slides up then the next slides down.

Comment: Activate jQuery top left and scale down demo to just the necessary html.

Comment: Improved lines indent in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'normal' for duration with Jquery fadeIn().

```
 $nextUL.fadeIn('normal');
```

Reference http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp

speed: Optional. Specifies the speed of the fading effect. Default value is 400 milliseconds
Possible values:

```
  milliseconds
  "slow"
  "fast"
```